# Using form_for -> no data received (Chrome), dropped connection (Safari)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, form-for, strong-parameters

I'm tearing my hair out trying to learn how to use the "form_for" helper.  I display a super simple form on `http://localhost:3000/demo/new`.  I then fill out three text_fields and try to create a new record.  In Chrome I get the "No Data Received" error and in Safari I get the "server unexpectedly dropped the connection" error.

I know that the form IS passing the parameters because a call to `raise parameters.inspect` shows that my parameters are being passed.  But, when I run the method, I get the above mentioned errors.  (By the way, the data is being saved into the database which makes this error all the more confusing.  In fact, the data is saved multiple times (7 to be exact), which suggests I am in some kind of loop.)

Here is my controller:

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @demos = Demo.all
  end

  def new
    @demo = Demo.new
  end

  def create
    # raise params.inspect
    @new_demo = Demo.create(demo_params)
    if @new_demo
      redirect_to 'index'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def demo_params
    params.require(:demo).permit(:fname, :lname, :city)
  end
end
```

Here is my view (with form_for):

```
<h1>Demo#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/demo/new.html.erb</p>


<%= form_for @demo, url: create_path(:action => 'create') do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :fname %>
    <%= f.text_field :lname %>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Here are my routes:

```
  get 'demo/index'

  get 'demo/show'

  get 'demo/new'

  get 'demo/edit'

  post '/demo/create'

  post '/demo/create' => 'demo#create', as: :create

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))',  :via => [:get, :post]
```

By the way, I changed the two "/demo/create" routes (adding the forward slash) just to try to fix the problem.  Because I was also getting errors that rails could not find route "/demo/create".  For the same reason, I added `(:action => 'create')` to the `create_path` statement.  Needless to say, these desperate efforts did not fix the problem.

I have spent an embarrassingly large amount of time trying to figure this out.  I would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes you can just write

```
resources :demo
```

and then simply use this in your views

```
<%= form_for @demo do |f| %>
```

P.S. you should change the name of Demo to Demos in controllers, views and routes if it's not a singular resource